# Editing Changed IB event fires before text is changed in a UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am firing the `updateFindName` method by linking it to the `Editing Changed` event in IB. The problem is that the method seems to fire before recording the actual change in the `UITextField` `uiFindName`. I wanted to update the `uiFindNameLabel`'s text to `uiFindName`'s placeholder text when the user clears all text in `uiFindName`, and it does, but only AFTER another character is typed into the `uiFindName`. Any tips?

```
- (IBAction)updateFindName:(id)sender {
    if ([uiFindNameLabel.text isNotEmpty]) {
        uiFindNameLabel.text = uiFindName.text;
    } else {
        uiFindNameLabel.text = uiFindName.placeholder;
    }
}
```

Note, `isNotEmpty` is just a method checking for empty strings.

Comment: I am not sure if i understood your question right, try editing did begin/end

Comment: I have a UILabel (uiFindNameLabel) and a UITextField (uiFindName) designed in IB. I have linked UITextField's "Editing Changed" outlet to execute the method above (updateFindName). The problem is that as I delete all the characters in the UITextField, the "uiFindNameLabel.text = uiFindName.placeholder;" line does not execute until I enter something into the field.

Comment: is the 'if' condition being called correctly when you key in each character?

Comment: If the placeholder appears **after** you type another character, did you check why the other character is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `UITextField`'s delegate method `– textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`.

There you can determine exactly what the text **before** and **after** the entered character should be.